# UIWebView Swift Intranet Side

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios9, intranet

I will open the Intranet Side from our company, but when I insert the URL, the webView is blank. 
In Addition with all other websites, like google, it works.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let url = NSURL (string: "url here")
  let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
  webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

Have someone an idea?

Thanks

Comment: check that your url is valid or not or else can you show your Url

Comment: the URl is valid, but it's an intranet side so I guess I have to trust de domain or so idk?